# preg_match for allowing letters, numbers and some special characters in PHP Preg_match()

Tags: php, preg-match

I have created a preg_match below with PHP Preg_match()

**preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -:]{5,15}$/")**

according to my condition

1. It should only contain Lower and upper case letters.
2. Should not contain numbers.
3. some special characters like (:,-)
4. Allow space as well.

But my code is accepting numbers, #, comma(,) special characters.

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z :-]{5,15}$` or escape the hyphen.

Comment: <?php
   $line = "Hello:,";
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z:,-]*$/",$line)) {
      echo "condition not match";
  } else {
      echo "condition match";
  }
?>

Comment: @nidhi: i want to allow space as well

Comment: replace it:  ^[a-zA-Z: ,-]*$  And give your string limits.

Comment: @nidhi: It worked but when I'm adding forward slash it stopped working. /^[a-zA-Z0-9-: .,/]{5,200}+$/

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z: ,-\/]*$/

Comment: @Nidhi: thanks. :)